# Sharejs is not loaded at client side

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, share.js

**Server**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var connect = require('connect');
var sharejs = require('share').server;
var server = connect(
  connect.static(__dirname + '/public/client/')
  );
var options = {db: {type: 'none'}};
sharejs.attach(server, options);

**var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
});**
```

**client**

```
<script src="/channel/bcsocket.js"></script>
<script src="/client/share/share.js"></script>
<script src="/share/ace.js"></script>
```

**Error**

```
**GET http://localhost:3000/channel/bcsocket.js 404 (Not Found)**

**GET http://localhost:3000/share/share.js 404 (Not Found)**

**GET http://localhost:3000/share/ace.js 404 (Not Found)**
```

**I'm unable to connect to client and server. I can't figure out what went wrong**

Comment: Which is the path of the Server js file? Make sure the connect.static path is correct.

Comment: its correct path bro still not getting..... even tried with all possible paths

Comment: Also, looks like you are not starting any server in the Server file. Is the last line in the Server file a comment (/** comment **/), otherwise what is app?

Comment: its not commented as stackoverflow is not accepting that way for posting question so I've to comment it in posting

Comment: The variable app is never defined, and the var server is defined twice. Looks like the the server file you posted is not the whole file, is not possible to figure out what you are trying to do if you do not post the whole file.

Comment: thank bro i figured out stuff thanks for helping me i've to use app instead of server in "sharejs.attach(server, options);"

Comment: I am happy I helped you debugging. But app is not defined in the code you posted. I would suggest to post the whole code when you ask a question, otherwise it is not possible to evaluate the problem and give you an answer, and becomes a bit of a loss of time for people trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the scripts cannot be found.

If server.js is in **myapp/server.js**,
the following

```
connect.static(__dirname + '/public/client/')
```

will serve static files form the **myapp/public/client/** folder.

Therefore, if the share.js file is in **myapp/public/client/share/share.js**, in the client.html you would have

```
<script src="/share/share.js"></script>
```

Also, you should configure the server to listen

```
var connect = require('connect');
var sharejs = require('share').server;
var server = connect(
      connect.static(__dirname + '/public/client/')
  );
var options = {db: {type: 'none'}};
sharejs.attach(server, options);

/** configure the server to listen on a port **/
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: you should configure the server to listen, see the reedited answer.

Comment: I tried the way u said it working but it arise new issues.that i cannot route to other page all other working pages not loading like localhost:3000/login stopped working. only that page is loaded correctly.